# Kivy , no attribute 'selection' for a listview

Tags: python, listview, python-2.7, kivy

I am trying to learn kivy : how to manipulate listview and its elements bind. Here is a part of my code where I have a problem .

Edit: I changed the code, or rather added it all , instead of just posting a part.

```
import re
import sys
import json
import requests
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint

import time
#Kivy Imports
import  kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix import label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty

from kivy.adapters.listadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.adapters import dictadapter
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
#Kivy version
kivy.require('1.7.0')
#MainLayout Class with the GridView
class MainLayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.text_input = ObjectProperty()  #reference to the textinput from .kv
        self.apps_list =  ObjectProperty()
        self.logo100 = ObjectProperty()        

        self.domain = self.ids.text_input.text 
        self.apps_list = self.ids.apps_list 
        self.logo100 = self.ids.logo100


        self.apps_list.adapter.bind(on_selected_item=self.callback)

    def on_enter(self):
        apps = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ,'f', 'g'}
        if apps != None :          
            list_adapter = ListAdapter(data = apps, 
                                       selection_mode = 'single',
                                       allow_empty_selection = True,
                                       cls = ListItemButton,
                                       sorted_keys=[])

        self.apps_list.adapter = list_adapter


    def callback(self, adapter):
        if len(self.adapter.selection) == 0:
            print "No selected item"
        else:
            print self.adapter.selection[0].text       


class WabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WabApp().run()
```

For the .kv file that I used :

```
<MainLayout>:

    rows: 2
    orientation: 'horizontal'


    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        orientation: 'vertical'
        row_force_default: True 
        row_default_height: 50

        Image:
            id: logo100
            source: 'logo100.png'
            size_hint: [.2, .1]
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size

        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            markup: True
            text: ''
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: [1.8, .1]
            multiline: False                    
            on_text_validate: root.on_enter()
            hint_text: 'test'
    ListView:
        id: apps_list
        allow_empty_selection: True
```

When I click on an item form the list, nothing happens.

I don't know also if I should use :

```
self.apps_list.adapter.bind(on_selected_item=self.callback)
```

or

```
self.apps_list.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback)
```

Actually, neither the first, nor the second shows a word on the console.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: is that the exact indentation of your code ?

Comment: No, I think it changed after pasting the code :-)

Comment: I just edited the identations of code. It looks more reasonable now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that you are doing wrong, but you main error is the number 2 of the following list:

1. You can use `on_selection change`. As far as I know there is no `on_selected_item`.
2. **You are binding the event before creating the object**. The follow instruction is in the **init**:

   ```
   self.apps_list.adapter.bind(on_selected_item=self.callback)
   ```

   but it should be in the on_enter after creating the new `ListAdapter`. It could be the last line of the method. See the codes below.

   ```
   def on_enter(self):
       ...
       self.apps_list.adapter = list_adapter
       self.apps_list.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback)
   ```
3. `MainLayout` doesn't contain any adapter. In the method `on_enter`, the references `self.adapter` should be changed to `adapter` (the method's parameter)  or `self.apps_list.adapter`.
4. The way you are creating the references to `domain`, `apps_list` and `logo100` is strange. I didn't know about the existence of the `ids` attribute in the `Widget` but you can use it directly. So, instead of:

   ```
   self.apps_list.adapter = list_adapter
   ```

   You can use:

   ```
   self.ids.apps_list.adapter = list_adapter
   ```

   **There is no need of the overloading the _*init*_ method at all.**

If you don't want to access the `apps_lists` through the `ids` attribute, then you can add attributes in the header of the kivy language:

```
<MainLayout>:
    text_input: text_input
    apps_list: apps_list
    logo100: logo100

    rows: 2
```

Here is the final working python code that includes all the mentioned changes. I omitted the  imports.

```
# ... your imports
class MainLayout(GridLayout):

    def on_enter(self):
        apps = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ,'f', 'g'}
        if apps != None :
            list_adapter = ListAdapter(data = apps, selection_mode = 'single',
            allow_empty_selection = True, cls = ListItemButton, sorted_keys=[])
        self.apps_list.adapter = list_adapter
        self.apps_list.adapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.callback)

    def callback(self, adapter):
        if len(adapter.selection) == 0:
            print "No selected item"
        else:
            print adapter.selection[0].text

class WabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WabApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample is all messed up, and very incomplete? Could you give a simple working app showing your problem?

I can give a couple of suggestions to fix things, one of which would cause the behaviour you see:

1) You do `self.apps_list =  ObjectProperty()` in the `__init__` method. This is wrong, it doesn't create an ObjectProperty with any useful behaviour, just creates a new attribute of the *instance* of your class, which you even replace on the next line! Instead, you should create properties at class level (i.e. the same level as function methods).

2) You include code that binds to an adapter's `on_selection_change` event, but also code in `on_enter` that replaces the adapter. Your example is too incomplete to know how or when the latter is called, but if it happens before you click the on a list item than your event can never be triggered because the adapter it's bound to has been replaced. This would give the behaviour you see. To fix it, don't replace the adapter, or rebind the callback to the new one.